# How do I ssh to nodes in a kubernetes/GKE cluster on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have created a `GKE` cluster for `Cassandra`. It has one node. I was to `ssh` on the node to run `nodetool` on the node. How do I `ssh` to a node of a cluster? I can see any option in the GUI

I am referring to https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-access-for-kubectl#kubeconfig, but unfortunately I can't see how to `ssh` to a node in a cluster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could Go to Compute Engine -> VM Instances, you will see your node there, and you could use the SSH button to access through SSH you could review this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance#gcetools) for more details.

Comment: thanks. Didn't realise that the nodes created by GKE are accessible via VMs interface.